# how to fix .driverfiles is missing from [SourceDisksFiles] error when creating a .cat file for a driver?

Tags: driver-signing

When I try to create a .cat file in Powershell using the command ".\inf2cat.exe /driver:"C:\DriverCert\xg20" /os:10_X64 /verbose", I end up with an error

```
Errors:
22.9.10: %drivername%.sys in [tileproxy.driverfiles] is missing from [SourceDisksFiles] section in xg20\tileproxy.inf; driver may not sign correctly until this is resolved.
```

here is the .inf file

```
;;;
;;; Tileproxy
;;;
;;;
;;; Copyright (c) 2007, 2008 Christian Buchner
;;;

[Version]
Signature   = "$Windows NT$"
Class       = "ActivityMonitor"                         ;This is determined by the work this filter driver does
ClassGuid   = {b86dff51-a31e-4bac-b3cf-e8cfe75c9fc2}    ;This value is determined by the Class
Provider    = %Buchner%
DriverVer   = 01/08/2008,1.0.0.0
CatalogFile=xg20gr.cat


[DestinationDirs]
DefaultDestDir          = 12
Tileproxy.DriverFiles     = 12            ;%windir%\system32\drivers

;;
;; Default install sections
;;

[DefaultInstall]
OptionDesc          = %ServiceDescription%
CopyFiles           = Tileproxy.DriverFiles

[DefaultInstall.Services]
AddService          = %ServiceName%,,Tileproxy.Service

;;
;; Default uninstall sections
;;

[DefaultUninstall]
DelFiles            = Tileproxy.DriverFiles



[DefaultUninstall.Services]
DelService = %ServiceName%,0x200      ;Ensure service is stopped before deleting

;
; Services Section
;

[Tileproxy.Service]
DisplayName      = %ServiceName%
Description      = %ServiceDescription%
ServiceBinary    = %12%\%DriverName%.sys        ;%windir%\system32\drivers\
Dependencies     = "FltMgr"
ServiceType      = 2                            ;SERVICE_FILE_SYSTEM_DRIVER
StartType        = 3                            ;SERVICE_DEMAND_START
ErrorControl     = 1                            ;SERVICE_ERROR_NORMAL
LoadOrderGroup   = "FSFilter Activity Monitor"
AddReg           = Tileproxy.AddRegistry

;
; Registry Modifications
;

[Tileproxy.AddRegistry]
HKR,"Instances","DefaultInstance",0x00000000,%DefaultInstance%
HKR,"Instances\"%Instance1.Name%,"Altitude",0x00000000,%Instance1.Altitude%
HKR,"Instances\"%Instance1.Name%,"Flags",0x00010001,%Instance1.Flags%

;
; Copy Files
;

[Tileproxy.DriverFiles]
%DriverName%.sys

;;
;; String Section
;;

[Strings]
Buchner                 = "Christian Buchner"
ServiceDescription      = "Tileproxy mini-filter driver"
ServiceName             = "Tileproxy"
DriverName              = "tileproxy"

;Instances specific information.
DefaultInstance         = "Tileproxy Instance"
Instance1.Name          = "Tileproxy Instance"
Instance1.Altitude      = "360000"
;Instance1.Flags         = 0x0          ; Allow all attachments
Instance1.Flags         = 0x1          ; Suppress automatic attachments
```

What should I change to get rid of the error?

In the [Tileproxy.DriverFiles] section, I tried to change the name from %DriverName%.sys to tileproxy.sys, still ended up with the same error. I also tried to add

```
[SourceDiskFiles]
%DriverName%.sys = 1

[SourceDisksNames]
1 = %DiskName%, ,
```

After the [Tileproxy.DriverFiles] section, but this didn't work and just ended up with the same error.